# Connection in Redis and Lua

Tags: nginx, redis, lua, openresty

This is my config:

```
local rc = require("resty.redis.connector").new({
                connect_timeout = 50,
                read_timeout = 5000,
                keepalive_timeout = 30000
            })

            local redis, err1 = rc:connect({
                url = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
            })

            if not redis then
                ngx.say( err1)    
            else
                ngx.say('connection fine')    
            end

            local ok, err = rc:set_keepalive(redis)
```

I'm getting this error:

> [error] 4044#0: *1068056 attempt to send data on a closed socket:
>   u:00007F2BABA05D48, c:0000000000000000, ft:0 eof:0, client: MY IP,
>   server: , request: "GET /foo HTTP/1.1", host: "SERVER IP"

When I disable keepalive setting, get this error:

> [error] 4147#0: *1089971 lua tcp socket connect timed out, when
>   connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379,

When I comment out the line related to rc:set_keepalive it works on single requests and crashes on 100 requests.

What is the best practices for connecting to Redis in Lua under huge requests?

Answer (score 5):

Most popular way of using redis in Lua is [lua-resty-redis](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#synopsis)

Regarding `[error] 4044#0: *1068056 attempt to send data on a closed socket`
I have experienced it when using [`set_timeouts(connect_timeout, send_timeout, read_timeout)`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#set_timeouts)  method.

When I switched to [`set_timeout(time)`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#set_timeout) method the error was gone.

I have not used [lua-resty-redis-connector](https://github.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-redis-connector) which I assume your are using in your code.

Comment: It worked for me too; except I have no clue why?

Answer (score -4):

Your code is incorrect.

1. [redis.new](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#new) doesn't accept any parameters.
2. [connect](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#connect) return `ok, err`. It doesn't make sense to pass `ok` value to `set_keepalive`.
3. [set_keepalive](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#set_keepalive) accepts 2 numbers as parameters.

RTFM, please, all your code looks like one big mess, sorry.

Comment: I think that you have not read his question carefully. He is not using lua-resty-redis (https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis) directly but via lua-resty-redis-connector (https://github.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-redis-connector)